# Why is only one new object created when called multiple times in `map`?

Tags: scala

As I understand it, a way to create a new `ArrayBuffer` with one element is to say

```
val buffer = ArrayBuffer(element)
```

or something like this:

```
val buffer = ArrayBuffer[Option[String]](None)
```

Suppose `x` is a collection with 3 elements.  I'm trying to create a map that creates a new 1-element `ArrayBuffer` for each element in `x` and associates the element in `x` with the new buffer.  (These are intentionally separate mutable buffers that will be modified by threads.)  I tried this:

```
x.map(elem => (elem, ArrayBuffer[Option[String]](None))).toMap
```

However, I found (using `System.identityHashCode`) that only one `ArrayBuffer` was created, and all 3 elements were mapped to the same value.

Why is this happening?  I expected that the tuple expression would be evaluated for each element of `x` and that this would result in a new `ArrayBuffer` being created for each evaluation of the expression.

What would be a good workaround?

I'm using Scala 2.11.

## Update

In the process of creating a reproducible example, I figured out the problem.  Here's the example; `Source` is an interface defined in our application.

```
  def test1(x: Seq[Source]): Unit = { 
    val containers = x.map(elem => (elem, ArrayBuffer[Option[String]](None))).toMap
    x.foreach(elem => println(
      s"test1: elem=${System.identityHashCode(elem)} container=${System.identityHashCode(containers(elem))}"))
    x.indices.foreach(n => containers(x(n)).update(0, Some(n.toString)))
    x.foreach(elem => println(s"resulting value: ${containers(elem)(0)}"))
  }
```

What I missed was that for the values of `x` I was trying to use, the class implementing `Source` was returning true for `equals()` for all combinations of values.  So the resulting map only had one key-value pair.

Apologies for not figuring this out sooner.  I'll delete the question after a while.

Comment: Are you sure that only one buffer is created? What happens if you add an element to the first buffer, does it appear in the other two buffers?

Comment: @ajb Could you provide complete minimal example that shows how you are using `identityHashCode`?

Comment: Did you by accident take the `identityHashCode` of the contents of the `ArrayBuffer`? Without a way to reproduce this issue not much useful can be said I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the `toMap`. If all three elements are `None` then you have in a Map just one element (as all have the same key).

I played a bit on [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/KbgyH0a/1) (remove the `.toMap` and you will have 3 `ByteArrays`)

let me know if I have misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to replicate the issue, for example

```
val m = 
  List(Some("a"), Some("b"), Some("c"))
    .map(elem => (elem, ArrayBuffer[Option[String]](None)))
    .toMap

m(Some("a")) += Some("42")

m
```

outputs

```
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Some[String],scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Option[String]]] = Map(
  Some(a) -> ArrayBuffer(None, Some(42)), 
  Some(b) -> ArrayBuffer(None), 
  Some(c) -> ArrayBuffer(None)
)
```

where we see `Some("42")` was added to one buffer whilst others were unaffected.